# Replace "Shift" key cap on MacBook Pro Retina 13-inch mid-2014

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair

After spilling tea on the corner of this MacBook Pro we tried using a blow-dryer to warm and dry it. We over-warmed it, melting the upper edge of the right-side `Shift` key cap. It melted downwards, and stops the key from traveling. So that Shift key no longer works.

Is it possible to replace a key cap on this keyboard?

- How to gracefully remove a key cap?
- Where to buy a replacement key cap?
- How to refit the replacement?

I seemed to have successfully removed the `Shift` key cap, after watching a couple videos on YouTube. But I am confused about what is correct operating position of the white circle-in-square scissoring parts on the left and right. The left one seems stuck up in the air, not flexing down. And the right one seems flat with no scissoring at all.

Comment: Related: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253703893?answerId=256951249022#256951249022